# How do I access old site on old hosting?

Tags: magento, dns, migration

I just recently pointed the domain to the new website but the owner would like to access his old website for his data.
The old website uses Magento while the new site uses Wordpress. The hosting for both websites are different. 
Can I access the old website through the IP address of the old hosting?

The old hosting suggested changing my hosts file, but it is not acceptable as the client would want to open both sites at the same time on the same browser

Comment: Anjxed, Think logically my friends , Do we have two houses with same exactly address, Not a all and so as with website. Cheer

Comment: @Anjxed: you can access the old site using the temporary url of old server. for this you also need to update WP base url with temp URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is also access from the temporary URL as well. So You need to do following things.

1. Get temporary URL from Cpanel.
2. Setup temporary URL for old website (magento) in `core_config_data` table.
3. Remove cache and try to access website with temporary URL in browser.

Comment: I asked my hosting to do this for me and they obliged